# How to upload all .txt files from folder and use folder name for text classification?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have directory with few subdirectory. Each subdirectory have .txt files. I try to create DataFrame with two columns:

```
text and sentiment
```

in [text] rows data from txt files and in [sentiment] rows: subfolder name for classification in future. For example:

```
           text | sentiment
data from 1.txt . folder name 1
data from 2.txt . folder name 1
data from 1.txt . folder name 2
data from 2.txt . folder name 2
```

I try to do this in this way:

```py
def load(class_name):
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    texts = lambda file_name: preprocess(open('./train/{}/*.txt'.format(class_name, file_name)).read())

    df['text'] = texts
    df['sentiment'] = class_name
    return df
```

```py
df_folder name 1 = load('folder name 1')
df_folder name 2 = load('folder name 2')
```

```py
df = df_folder name 1.append(df_folder name 2)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['text'], keep='first', inplace=True)
df = df.sample(frac=1)
df.head()
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop around the sub directories and the files within them, save the data to a list then make it a DataFrame.

```
data = list()
for folder in os.listdir('./cwd'):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join('./cwd', folder)):
        with open(os.path.join('./cwd', folder, file)) as text:
            words = text.read()
            data.append([words, folder])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['text', 'sentiment'])
```

The first for loop will loop through all your folders (you will have to change the "./cwd" to wherever the folders are). The second will loop through all the files in that folder. The with statement will open and close your files, save the text, then append the text and the folder name.